# push first commit on develop branch and main branch clean

Tags: git, github

I would like to push my first commit on develop branch and then create a clean main or master branch.

Before push my first commit I use this command to create my develop branch from HEAD

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/develop
```

When I push my commit on Github only develop branch exists. It is exactly what I want.

But if I create a main branch, the branch is not empty, they are the same files than my develop branch. It is not what I want.

Below a representation of what I want.

```
main    ======> Clean
develop ======> myFirstCommit
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It *is* possible to create totally-independent streams of commits in a single Git repository. That's not a normal way to work, though, and if you succeed at it for this case, you'll wind up regretting it. A Git branch name cannot exist without having a commit, so what you *do* want to do instead is start with a commit on `main` that has just a `README` and/or similar files in it, and then to create `develop` so that it identifies the *same commit* initially, and then to add your first *real* commit as your *second* commit.

Answer (score 2):

Branches are a file under .git/refs/heads/ that contain a reference to a commit. The branch that .git/HEAD points to moves along if you add new commits. There is nothing like an empty branch. As long as both refs point to the root of the repo, the two branches will always be the same.